# How to select dropdown option with Casperjs and fillSelectors

Tags: javascript, forms, html-select, casperjs

I have the following form:

```
<form name="security_page_toplevel_page_itsec_settings" method="post" action="options.php">
    <select id="itsec_strong_passwords_roll" name="itsec_strong_passwords[roll]">
        <option value="admin">admin</option>
        <option value="subscriber">subscriber</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

but I am unable to select the "subscriber" option with the following code:

```
this.fillSelectors('form#security_page_toplevel_page_itsec_settings', {
    'select[name="itsec_strong_passwords[roll]"]': 'subscriber'
}, true);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

The name attribute of the form is not the same as the id attribute.

You have to select the `form` using

```
this.fillSelectors('form[name="security_page_toplevel_page_itsec_settings"]', {
    'select[name="itsec_strong_passwords[roll]"]': 'subscriber'
}, true);
```

If this does not work, you could try explicitly setting the select option in the page context:

```
var index = 2; // the index to select, you may calculate the index programatically from the option value
this.evaluate(function(index) {
    var sel = document.querySelector('form[name="security_page_toplevel_page_itsec_settings"] select[name="itsec_strong_passwords[roll]"]');
    sel.selectedIndex = index;
    sel.onchange();
}, index);
```

Comment: I have used your syntax but it still doesn't work. There must be something else but I don't know why. I have tried not validating the form (using the "false" argument) and then only explicitly validating the form by clicking on the save button (I would prefer using this method) but it still doesn't work.

Comment: I added another possibility where you select the index. But I also tried your code with [this minimal example](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ea5a33589a62a4a1cab0). It works for me. You can try it yourself.

Comment: Actually the two solutions work! My problem was that I was trying to see the effects of `fillSelectors` by reloading my page with the F5 key, but for some reasons changes were not displayed this way! Only when I explicitly reclicked on a link leading to my page were the changes displayed... lot of wasted time for this. The screenshots allowed me to see that your functions were indeed working correctly. Thanks anyway!